# using hook updateQuantity on prestashop 1.4

Tags: hook, prestashop

I'm new to prestashop.

I'm working on prestashop 1.4 and I would like to invoke an event just after updating stock. 
I've read some subjects talking about the updateQuantity hook or some other defined hooks action.
Someone can put me on the right way with a simple example

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use action **hookUpdateQuantity**.
If you want use this action on your module first you must register on you module function **install()** after create function for this hook.

```
public function install()
{
  return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('updateQuantity');
}

public function hookUpdateQuantity($params)
{
   // for example send Customer Alert information about product quantity 
    if ($this->_customer_qty && $params['product']['quantity'] > 0)
        $this->sendCustomerAlert((int)$params['product']['id'], 0);
}
```

Comment: updateQuantity = Quantity is updated only when the customer effectively place his order. This is that what you must use in aftre update quantity of product.